# Javascript error `function not defined` when trying to import GLTFLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to write a program that shows a 3D model in a modal. Everything works until I try to add an import statement. As soon as I add the statement
`import {GLTFLoader} from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";`
anywhere in the code I get a reference error stating that any function I try to call is not defined. I have the same problem with any other import I try to add. I tried loading the import in other places in the code but that resulted in an error as well. The error occurred even if the import statement was in a function that wasn't called. Does anybody know where my error could be? The following is the beginning of my code if that is helpful.

```
import {GLTFLoader} from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
var soupbowl = soupbowl || {}; //Create namespace
  /*
  creates canvas for 2D soup animation
  */
  soupbowl.twod = function() {


      var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('soupcanvas');
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

      // Get the canvas dimensions
      let width = canvas.offsetWidth; // Width of the scene
      let height = canvas.offsetHeight; // Height of the scene
      canvas.setAttribute('width', 600);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', 600);
      canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
      canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);

      if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
      }
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      //create soupplate
      soupbowl.createPlate();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61944723/8626932

Answer (score 0):

I think your file path must begin with "../"

in this place `import {GLTFLoader} from "../ three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";`

and don't use 'var'.
use 'const' :)

Comment: and GLTFLoader.js must have something like this ``export function GLTFLoader (some_props) { ...``

Comment: Thanks! I changed these things but I still get the same error. Is there anything else that you think could cause the problem?

Comment: maybe show the `GLTFLoader.js` ?

Comment: and `import` must be at the beginning of the file ( code )

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've loaded [three.js via NPM or a CDN](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation)?

Try going to your web page and typing `__THREE__` in the developer console. This should log the version of the library that is currently loaded.

Assuming three.js is loaded, here's how you can load the GLTF:

```js
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(filename, gltf => {

    // Use the loaded gltf here

});
```

Or use async/await in an async function instead:

```js
async function initScene() {
    
    const gltf = await loader.loadAsync(filename);
    
    // Use the loaded gltf here
}
```